# open spefic sms thread in android

Tags: android, listview, sms

I am trying to develop a sms application. I have succeeded in retrieving all the sms from the inbox in a list view, but now i am stuck at one point. I want that, when the user clicks on any of the thread it should open that thread in detailed view. How can i do that?
I am pasting the picture about what i exactly want and also the code which i have written to retrieve the list of sms.

```
public class Inbox extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inbox);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    List<String> msgList = getSMS();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, msgList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public List<String> getSMS() {
    List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
        sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);
    }
    return sms;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_inbox, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do to achieve this.

When the user clicks on any message in the ListView, you can retrieve that number corresponding to that message and store it in a variable.

Next you pass the intent to the Activity which is supposed to show the detailed view, along with the number which was retrieved in the last step. Here, you get all the messages from the database by using a cursor but display them if and only if the number matches with the one which was received in the last step.